# AD Authentication for Linux VMs

Tags: linux, security, users, authentication

If you have 100's of Linux VM's is it possible to get them all authenticating with an AD LDAP, but more importantly there is no local id needed in every single /etc/passwd and /etc/group of the 100 VM's?

E.g a file tells Linux not to use /etc/passwd and /etc/group and goes straight to AD LDAP only?

Comment: `/etc/nsswitch.conf` should be the file you're looking for.

Comment: It's not a good idea (generally), though. You should have at least an administrator-level account locally in the case that the network is unavailable

Comment: you have to have at least root in `/etc/passwd` , tools (e.g. apache) might or might no need /etc/passwd also, while users, products and functional user might use LDAP. be sure to keep a local emrgency admin login available.

Comment: Yes, of course you'd have the root etc in the /etc/passwd, I'm on about linking it to Microsoft AD and not having any trace of accounts in either /etc/group or /etc/passwd. It seems silly to have local accounts at all.
Can't this be done with NIS or Samba? SMB?

Answer (score 0):

You need a NSS/PAM service running on your Linux boxes such as [sssd](https://sssd.io/), [nss-pam-ldapd](https://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/) (aka nslcd) or Samba's winbindd.

Both have NSS and PAM frontend modules which you have to reference in /etc/nsswitch.conf and /etc/pam.d.

You can find various how-tos describing such a setup for using MS AD as LDAP server. You should read several of them to understand all the details, especially UID and GID number mappings.